# C# - access specifier -for accessing method in the same namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, inheritance

I have the below code in my C# program:

```
namespace test
{        
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string val = "0";    
            parent o1 = new parent();               
        }
    }

    public class parent
    {
        string test1()
        {
            string val = "2";
            return val;
        }
    }

    public class child:parent
    {
        string test1()
        {
            string val = "3";
            return val;
        }
    }
}
```

How to access the method test of class parent?
I tried by creating object of parent but unable to access the method. 
what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [Access Modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx). Use `internal` or `public` with method because if you not mention it then it will be consider as private

```
public class parent
{
    internal string test1()
    {
        string val = "2";
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: @X-Tech You can also use the classes and methods defined using internal access modifier in other assembly by defining friend assemblies

Comment: Yes you are right, but I am talking about method's access modifier only because OP did  not mention it for his method

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the public access modifier before the method declaration. By default the method is private